# How to show that a function is 1-periodic when it is obvious?

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that the function $ f(x) = x - \lfloor x\rfloor  $ is one-periodic.  That function is obviously the rational part of x, which is obviously 1-periodic, but how can I prove it?  I also have to show that the function is differentiable on $\mathbb R - \mathbb Z $, which is also obvious to me as it is continuous.  I think I might just be rusty and seeing a proof of this could help me.  Thank you.

Comment: Ahh,obviousness..The bane of mathematicians. Anyway, when you apply the definition of periodicity here what do you get? You need $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for some nonzero constant $T$. Which is the required $T$?

Comment: T is 1, because I'm proving 1-periodicity.

Comment: And one more thing-the fact that a function is continuous does not mean that it is differentiable.See here-  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\lfloor x+1\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor+1$. Therefore $$(x+1)-\lfloor x+1\rfloor=(x+1)-(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$$

Answer (score 1):

Stella's answer covers the first case. 

As for the differentiability of $f(x)$, notice that the derivative of the floor function, $⌊x⌋$ is $0$ at non-integers and not defined at integers. 

So in this case, in $\Bbb{R-Z}$, the derivative is equal to $$(x-⌊x⌋)'=(x)'-(⌊x⌋)'=1-0=1$$